# typescript: what is async function definition syntax?

Tags: typescript

I'm new to typescript and I'm struggling with some basic syntax questions. Probably these are so basic that I wasn't able to find a good guide / tutorial that explains the stuff.

Here is the code:

```
export const createEntity = async <T extends EntityConstructor>(
  Constructor: T,
  input: Partial<InstanceType<T>>,
): Promise<InstanceType<T>> => {
  const instance = Constructor.create(input);
  return validateAndSaveEntity(instance as InstanceType<T>);
};
```

1. what does `< >` do after the `async` keyword?
2. I see that the code in `( )` after the `< >` keyword specify input variables and their types.
3. what does `< >` do in `Promise< >`?

Answer (score 1):

1. `<T extends EntityConstructor>` is a type definition but the compiler declares the type based on given variables eg.

```
// type of output will be 'string'
let output = identity<string>("myString");
```

or

```
// type of output will be 'string', the compiler will figure out `T`
// based on the value passed in
let output = identity("myString");
```

or

```
// type of output will be 'number'
let output = identity(8675309);
```

In your given Case that memans the `<T extends EntityConstructor>` will take most likely an object with the same parameters as `EntityConstructor` and can obtain other variables declared by you

2. ON THIS IM NOT CERTAIN!!!

My take is that it will expect a function to be passed on through observable that will have or need those parameters.

3. The Promise type is declared in `< >` so you could do `Promise<string>` and everthing that is not a string wont be passed on as Promise

Comment: 3. what do you mean by "Promise type"? I thought "Promise" is a type of object of its own. For example: variable x can be a "Promise object" or a "string object". What is a string Promise?  Do you mean the return type of the Promise?

Comment: 1. I can understand `T extends EntityConstructor`, what I don't get is how `< >` is related to the `async` keyword. Does `async` also has a type declaration?